# Inline assembly function parameter has same name with local variable

Tags: solidity, assembly

```
contract Test {
    function f() public returns(uint r) {
        uint x = 100;
        assembly {
            function f(x) -> y { y := add(x, 1) }
            r := f(100)
        }
    }
}
```

Use the latest compiler to compile this Test contract, got a error:

```
DeclarationError: Cannot access local Solidity variables from inside an inline assembly function.
```

Is it right or bug?

Comment: Hi there. Are you asking whether this should be allowed, given that the two `x` variables are in a different scope?